# JAXB XML parsing no content when parsing AWS S3 Bucket XML

Tags: java, xml, amazon-s3, jaxb

I am currently trying to parse the XML output from an AWS S3 Bucket using the JAXB library. I am receiving no errors though the ListBucketObject is getting no content. I've tried adding XmlAccessorTypes to the Java POJO models with little success. Any suggestions?

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult
    xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <Name>public-test-bucket</Name>
    <Prefix></Prefix>
    <Marker></Marker>
    <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
    <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
    <Contents>
        <Key>202008281741/</Key>
        <LastModified>2020-08-31T15:38:24.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>&quot;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&quot;</ETag>
        <Size>0</Size>
        <Owner>
            <ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID>
            <DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName>
        </Owner>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>202008281741/161_209_2_0_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000</Key>
        <LastModified>2020-08-31T15:38:49.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>&quot;0834c2470b1e5183c27f7c67b589ff64&quot;</ETag>
        <Size>48328</Size>
        <Owner>
            <ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID>
            <DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName>
        </Owner>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>202008281741/161_209_2_1_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000</Key>
        <LastModified>2020-08-31T15:39:22.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>&quot;fca85f403ba0743c8a8559096728e86b&quot;</ETag>
        <Size>49259</Size>
        <Owner>
            <ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID>
            <DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName>
        </Owner>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>202008281741/161_209_2_2_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000</Key>
        <LastModified>2020-08-31T15:39:22.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>&quot;d4d9b9a1fdca74bda124548b7c303595&quot;</ETag>
        <Size>51296</Size>
        <Owner>
            <ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID>
            <DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName>
        </Owner>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>202008281741/161_209_2_3_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000</Key>
        <LastModified>2020-08-31T15:39:22.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>&quot;17b32ca673db491695b529c88397d583&quot;</ETag>
        <Size>53479</Size>
        <Owner>
            <ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID>
            <DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName>
        </Owner>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>test/</Key>
        <LastModified>2020-08-31T15:37:08.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>&quot;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&quot;</ETag>
        <Size>0</Size>
        <Owner>
            <ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID>
            <DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName>
        </Owner>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
    <Contents>
        <Key>test/33.txt</Key>
        <LastModified>2020-08-31T15:37:26.000Z</LastModified>
        <ETag>&quot;182be0c5cdcd5072bb1864cdee4d3d6e&quot;</ETag>
        <Size>2</Size>
        <Owner>
            <ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID>
            <DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName>
        </Owner>
        <StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
    </Contents>
</ListBucketResult>
```

Driver.java

```
package parseXML;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;



public class Driver {
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                "<ListBucketResult xmlns=\"http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/\"><Name>public-test-bucket</Name><Prefix></Prefix><Marker></Marker><MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys><IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated><Contents><Key>202008281741/</Key><LastModified>2020-08-31T15:38:24.000Z</LastModified><ETag>&quot;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&quot;</ETag><Size>0</Size><Owner><ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID><DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents><Contents><Key>202008281741/161_209_2_0_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000</Key><LastModified>2020-08-31T15:38:49.000Z</LastModified><ETag>&quot;0834c2470b1e5183c27f7c67b589ff64&quot;</ETag><Size>48328</Size><Owner><ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID><DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents><Contents><Key>202008281741/161_209_2_1_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000</Key><LastModified>2020-08-31T15:39:22.000Z</LastModified><ETag>&quot;fca85f403ba0743c8a8559096728e86b&quot;</ETag><Size>49259</Size><Owner><ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID><DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents><Contents><Key>202008281741/161_209_2_2_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000</Key><LastModified>2020-08-31T15:39:22.000Z</LastModified><ETag>&quot;d4d9b9a1fdca74bda124548b7c303595&quot;</ETag><Size>51296</Size><Owner><ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID><DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents><Contents><Key>202008281741/161_209_2_3_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000</Key><LastModified>2020-08-31T15:39:22.000Z</LastModified><ETag>&quot;17b32ca673db491695b529c88397d583&quot;</ETag><Size>53479</Size><Owner><ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID><DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents><Contents><Key>test/</Key><LastModified>2020-08-31T15:37:08.000Z</LastModified><ETag>&quot;d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&quot;</ETag><Size>0</Size><Owner><ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID><DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents><Contents><Key>test/33.txt</Key><LastModified>2020-08-31T15:37:26.000Z</LastModified><ETag>&quot;182be0c5cdcd5072bb1864cdee4d3d6e&quot;</ETag><Size>2</Size><Owner><ID>1eca891ffebb61124e238208a9df374b04731545fa5a646e8942a877bed5a24e</ID><DisplayName>aws-sandbox</DisplayName></Owner><StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass></Contents></ListBucketResult>";

        //convert into xml
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListBucketResult.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            ListBucketResult listBucketResult = (ListBucketResult) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
            
            List<Contents> contents = listBucketResult.getContents();
            contents.forEach((content) -> System.out.println(content.getKey())); 
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

ListBucketResult.java

```
package parseXML;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ListBucketResult", namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/")
public class ListBucketResult {

    private String Name;
    private String Prefix;
    private String Marker;
    private int MaxKeys;
    private boolean IsTruncated;
    private List<Contents> Contents;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return Prefix;
    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        Prefix = prefix;
    }

    public String getMarker() {
        return Marker;
    }

    public void setMarker(String marker) {
        Marker = marker;
    }

    public int getMaxKeys() {
        return MaxKeys;
    }

    public void setMaxKeys(int maxKeys) {
        MaxKeys = maxKeys;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public boolean isIsTruncated() {
        return IsTruncated;
    }

    public void setIsTruncated(boolean isTruncated) {
        IsTruncated = isTruncated;
    }

    public List<Contents> getContents() {
        return Contents;
    }

    public void setContents(List<Contents> contents) {
        Contents = contents;
    }

}
```

Contents.java

```
package parseXML;

public class Contents {
    private String Key;
    private String LastModified;
    private String ETag;
    private String Size;
    private Owner Owner;
    private String StroageClass;
    
    public String getKey() {
        return Key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        Key = key;
    }
    public String getLastModified() {
        return LastModified;
    }
    public void setLastModified(String lastModified) {
        LastModified = lastModified;
    }
    public String getETag() {
        return ETag;
    }
    public void setETag(String eTag) {
        ETag = eTag;
    }
    public String getSize() {
        return Size;
    }
    public void setSize(String size) {
        Size = size;
    }
    public Owner getOwner() {
        return Owner;
    }
    public void setOwner(Owner owner) {
        this.Owner = owner;
    }
    public String getStroageClass() {
        return StroageClass;
    }
    public void setStroageClass(String stroageClass) {
        StroageClass = stroageClass;
    }
    
    

}
```

Owner.java

```
package parseXML;

public class Owner {
    private String ID;
    private String DisplayName;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public void setID(String iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return DisplayName;
    }
    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. Handling the Namespace
2. Getters, Setters, and Field Names

**Handling the Namespace**

Instead of declaring the namespace on the root element of the `ListBucketResult` class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListBucketResult", namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/")
```

Use this instead:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListBucketResult")
```

And for the namespace, handle that in a `package-info.java` file. This is created in your `parseXML` package, in the same way as your classes, but has the following contents:

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package parseXML;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

This ensures that all the elements in the XML file are qualified - not just those relating to the fields in the `ListBucketResult` class.

**Getters, Setters, and Field Names**

I think the way you have named your Java fields is causing problems for your getters/setters, as they do not conform to the JavaBeans naming conventions.

Example: In your `ListBucketResult`, you have this:

```
private List<Contents> Contents;

public List<Contents> getContents() {
    return Contents;
}

public void setContents(List<Contents> contents) {
    Contents = contents;
}
```

The JavaBeans (and wider Java) naming convention is to use field names with camelcase - so, in this case `contents`. And then to match the getter and setter names accordingly - by capitalizing the first letter of the field: `getContents`, `setContets`.

For your XML, this means you also need to annotate the field name in the class, so that JAXB knows the Java field called `contents` maps to the XML element called `Contents`.

I choose to annotate the fields themselves - so I add an `@XmlAccessorType` annotation to the class, and then an `@XmlElement` annotation to the field.

I end up with this - ignoring all the other fields, for now:

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "ListBucketResult", namespace = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ListBucketResult {

    @XmlElement(name="Name")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name="Contents")
    private List<Contents> contents;

    public List<Contents> getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void setContents(List<Contents> contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }
}
```

Then, in the `Contents` class I have to do something similar - for example (again, ignoring all the fields except for `key`):

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Contents {

    @XmlElement(name="Key")
    private String key;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

If you repeat this process for the remaining fields in your classes, you will have fully populated Java objects.

**Results**

By making only the above changes, my driver code (the same as your code) now prints out the following results:

```
202008281741/
202008281741/161_209_2_0_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000
202008281741/161_209_2_1_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000
202008281741/161_209_2_2_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000
202008281741/161_209_2_3_255_1_97_InitializedAnalysis_219_0m(AMSL)_0.000000_-1_-1.000000_-1.000000
test/
test/33.txt
```

By applying the same changes to all the remaining field names, you would be able to handle the complete XML file.